# Change SQL select command operator in WHERE part at runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, selectcommand

I am trying to implement user rights management in a project with C# and asp.net. What I want to do is simply showing the relevant pages to the user according to the login name. I wrote lots of SQL select commands.

Is there a way to change the WHERE part only in a SQL select command?
I mean for example when a user clicks on a button

`...WHERE REGION='IC'` becomes `...WHERE REGION<>'IC'`

Or can you please advise any other practices to implement such a scenario?

Thanks in advance

Edit: My select commands

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Firma,BOLGE,SUM(KDV_MATRAHI) AS TUTAR from SATISLAR_T WHERE DAHIL=0 AND REGION=REGION  GROUP BY Firma,BOLGE UNION SELECT Firma,CH_YETKI_KODU AS BOLGE, SUM(KDV_MATRAHI)  AS TUTAR
FROM LNX_STD_6_016_01_SLSINVOICES WHERE MALZEME_OZEL_KODU<>'DİĞER GLR'   AND REGION=REGION GROUP BY REGION, Firma) AS BOLGE
  PIVOT
(
SUM(TUTAR)
    FOR Firma IN ([008] ,[009] ,[010] ,[011], [012], [013], [014] ,[015],[016])
)AS pvt
```

After user clicks on the button:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Firma,BOLGE,SUM(KDV_MATRAHI) AS TUTAR from SATISLAR_T WHERE DAHIL=0 AND REGION='IC'  GROUP BY Firma,BOLGE UNION SELECT Firma,CH_YETKI_KODU AS BOLGE, SUM(KDV_MATRAHI)  AS TUTAR
FROM LNX_STD_6_016_01_SLSINVOICES WHERE MALZEME_OZEL_KODU<>'DİĞER GLR'   AND REGION<>'IC' GROUP BY CH_YETKI_KODU, Firma) AS BOLGE
  PIVOT
(
SUM(TUTAR)
    FOR Firma IN ([008] ,[009] ,[010] ,[011], [012], [013], [014] ,[015],[016])
)AS pvt
```

Comment: Of course it's possible to change the WHERE part. What do you mean with "at runtime". Please show us your code and your selects (give a useful example of what you want to do).

Comment: Are you working with ad-hoc queries or stored procedures?

Comment: By "at runtime" I mean when a user clicks a button, the code will run inside the click handler. I added select into the original question.
I am not using stored procedures.

Comment: This is actually about giving users different views according to their rights.

Comment: So build your query on the side where you're building shown above. What's the problem you are facing? It's all about concatenating strings.

Comment: I dont want to write queries for every other user. I just want to change the WHERE part of the query based on the user right. 
I mean when a specific user logs in who has the right to see the customer from "IC" region the first query should run. There could be lots of different regions or lots of other filter parameters.

Comment: I don't understand what are your objections. You want to change WHERE clause - do change it. You are working with ad-hocs. Do change your ad-hoc "based on user permissions". Each one of them has his own app instance, doesn't he?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is to [pass a parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

```
where 
  ((@Param=1 and REGION = 'IC')
    or
  (@Param=2 and REGION <> 'IC'))
```

Comment: I like this idea, perhaps to be slightly more efficient you could have two different procedures/views one that is Not Equal and one that is Equal. 

if the op is using procedures and there's more logic than just a Where clause prehaps put that into a view and then 2 procedures

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *formatting* when forming SQL:

```
// depending on condition 
// we put either REGION='IC' or REGION<>'IC' instead of {0} place holder
string sql = string.Format( 
    // Make slq readable and maintainable, use @ verbatim strings
  @"select ...
     where {0} 
     ...", condition ? "REGION='IC'" : "REGION<>'IC'"); 

using (var command = new SqlCommand(connection)) {
  command.CommandText = sql;
  ...
}
```

In case of *C# 6.0*, *string interpotaion* is an alternative:

```
string sql =  
  $@"select ...
      where {(condition ? "REGION='IC'" : "REGION<>'IC'")} 
      ...";
```

Comment: Well this solution seem to solve this problem, I did not understand how to use it at first look but I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to implement that functionality would be to have the two different queries as functions and call the appropriate ones depending on the state of the button. No clever code or tricks required.

Comment: Actually I have many SQL commands and lots of users so that will mean maybe writing double or triple queries again.

Comment: I understand your concern. The reply below by Dmitry is a good enough solution then, however bear in mind that maintenance of such code could turn into a problem later down the road.

Comment: So can you recommend any other way for this? Just tell me few words for me to google it.